# Ubuntu server 18.04 LTS installation failing

Tags: server, system-installation, uefi, 18.04

I have an old-ish HP Z210 workstation that I want to install Ubuntu server on. The installation from USB goes almost perfectly until it gets to update UEFI, where it gets this error:

[image: screenshot]

Dropping to the shell I install efibootmgr and run:

```
$ sudo efibootmgr
BootCurrent: 0011
Timeout: 0 seconds
No BootOrder is set; firmware will attempt recovery
Boot000A* Windows Boot Manager
```

Armed with my very limited knowledge of UEFI, I run:

```
$ sudo efibootmgr -B -b 000A
Could not delete variable: Invalid argument
```

Which is similar, but different to what the installer came up with. Any clue what I might need to do to fix/nuke the old Windows boot? I've tried resetting the BIOS to factory defaults, and looked for any UEFI security settings, but no joy.

Comment: You might try installing your Ubuntu server on a different UEFI system, then move the hard drive into the HP.  It might just be an installation issue with that UEFI firmware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As rcpao suggested, I used a known working system as a surrogate, installed Ubuntu successfully, and put it in the troublesome computer and it works perfectly.

I tried other things like forcing it to boot from legacy, flashing the BIOS, disabling all BIOS security settings, plugging the drive into different SATA ports, but that made no difference. So there's something funky about this particular motherboard/BIOS that just causes grief if you want to install anything but Windows.